# How does Dispatch.main.async "update the UI"?

Tags: swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

I've been using Swift for a little while and GCD still confuses me a bit.

I've read:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

As well as the Apple docs on dispatch:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch

I understand the overall concept that GCD allows multiple tasks to be run on different threads (I think that's right).

What I don't quite understand is how `Dispatch.main.async` "updates the UI".

For example if I make a call to an api somewhere and data is returned - say it takes 5 seconds to return all the data, then how does using `Dispatch.main.async` help with updating the UI? How does `Dispatch.main.async` know what UI to update?

And i still don't quite get the place of GCD and why instead can't some kind of observer or a delegate or a closure be used that is called when all the data is loaded?

And re: "updating the UI" with GCD if I'm making an api call but not using the data immediately eg. just storing the data in an array until I decide to use it is there then any need to use `Dispatch.main.async`?

And I've been using firebase/firestore as a db for a little while now. Firebase has it's own listeners and runs asynchronously. I still can't get a great answer re: the best way to handle the asynchronous return from firebase in iOS/Swift. For example when my app loads if I go to firebase to get data to populate a tableviewcontroller what is the best way to know when all the data has returned? I've been using a delegate for this but was wondering if and how `Dispatch.main.async` might be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI the reason that all of the UI code needs to go on the main thread is because drawing is a (relatively in CPU time) long and expensive process involving many data structures and millions of pixels.  The graphics code essentially needs to lock a copy of all of the UI resources when its doing a frame update, so you cannot edit these in the middle of a draw, otherwise you would have wierd artifacts if you went and changed things half way through when the system is rendering those objects.  Since all the drawing code is on the main thread, this lets he system block main until its done rendering, so none of your changes get processed until the current frame is done.  Also since some of the drawing is cached (basically rendered to texture until you call something like setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsLayout) if you try to update something from a background thread its entirely possible that it just won't show up and will lead to inconsistent state, which is why you aren't supposed to call any UI code on the background threads.

Comment: I understand why this limitation was chosen at the time. But you make it sound like a law of physics, which it certainly is not. The design decision usually dates back to when only a single application could be run at a time. Today several applications run at the same time and update the UI at the same time. So all the problems you describe have been solved. The restriction only applies within an application.

Comment: Thats not true; they all update their own drawing which is then composited and sent to the graphics card in one batch for a single frame.  They are not concurrently modifying the GPU state; that is simply not how modern graphics hardware works.  You setup the data state and make as few graphics calls as possible and you certainly don't change state in the middle of the render.  Look at the Metal SDK if you want to see how GPU drawing actually works.

Comment: My comment can obviously be misunderstood. You are right that certain UI actions cannot happen at the same time. If two applications try to do it at the same time, the operating system will properly synchronize them. It could do the same for two threads within a single application. But instead of automatic synchronization, the *main* thread limitation is imposed.

Comment: If you mean that the OS could synchonize everything by dispatching all of the UI calls back to the main thread it certainly could; that also sounds horribly inefficent, which is not what you want in a time critical section of code like rendering.  Thats why its not implemented that way.  it has nothing to do with being "old" design decision; it has to do with beign an efficient design decision.

Comment: Thanks for the answers/comments.  Could I clarify something re: this sentence "So when these tasks are finished and you want to update the UI (e.g. to display the result), you must do so on the main thread. With Dispatch.main.async you can ask GCD to run a piece of code on the main thread. GCD doesn't know about the UI." I have seen GCD being used with api calls to a restful service eg. to load movie info into a tableviewcontroller. But if the tableviewcontroller is already run on the main thread then why would I ask GCD to run a piece of code on the main thread?

Comment: You only have to dispatch back to main when you are on a background thread.  Typically you run tasks that take a very long time (relative to CPU time) to execute, like loading and parsing a file, or making a network call because you don't want to block the main thread.  In the compeltion handler for these functions you then dispatch back to main after you already have the compelted the long running task so that they UI gets updated on the next draw call.

Comment: Thanks @Josh. But I thought the idea is that the main thread just keeps running whatever UI related stuff is happening while the background thread - eg. a network call -  is executing its tasks. When the background thread task is completed why do I need to dispatch back to main? If the background task is completed (eg. all data is returned) and the main thread is just doing what it always was doing why do I need to get back to main from the finished background thread?

Comment: You only have to dispatch back if your background needs to update the UI.  example: I download and image on a background thread that takes 1 second. During this time the screen continues to draw at 60 times a second (possibly more or less on the new promotion idsplays).   When the image is done I dispatch back to main and set the image as an imageView's image property and the system rerenders the image view on the main thread's next draw call.  Counter Example:  my image download fails so I do nothing and leave the palceholder image in place.  No need to dispatch to main.

Comment: I think i kind of get it. But let's say the image view is an IBOutlet called mainImgView. And the downloaded image you retrieve on the background thread is stored as a UIImage called downloadedImg. Why can't you just wait till the background thread completes (ie the image is downloaded) and the just set mainImgView.image = downloadedImg?

Comment: Because the only way you know that its done, other than by constantly polling is when the completion handler gets called on the background thread.  ie you get notified its done on the background thread so you have to send the draw commands back to the main thread from the place you got notified, which is inside the compeltion handler on the backgroudn thread.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. That's great.

Answer (score 6):

`Dispatch.main.async` does not *update the UI*. The story goes into a different direction: If you want to *update* the UI, you must do so from the *main* thread. If you're current code is not running on the main thread, `Dispatch.main.async` is the most convenient way to have some code run on the *main* thread.

It's an old restrictions that affects most operating systems: UI related actions such as changing elements in the UI must only be called from a specific thread, usually the so called *main* thread.

In many cases that's not a problem since your UI related code usually acts when triggered by some UI event (user clicking or tapping, key pressed etc.). These event callback happen on the main thread. So there is no threading issue.

With GCD, you can run long-running tasks on separate threads so the tasks doesn't slow down or even block the UI. So when these tasks are finished and you want to update the UI (e.g. to display the result), you must do so on the main thread.  With `Dispatch.main.async` you can ask GCD to run a piece of code on the main thread. GCD doesn't know about the UI. Your code must know what to update. GCD just runs your code on the desired thread.

If at the end of your tasks there is nothing to display or otherwise update in the UI, then you don't need to call `Dispatch.main.async`.

**Update re Firebase**

The Firebase Database client performs all network and disk operations in separate background thread **off** the main thread.

The Firebase Database client invokes all callbacks to your code **on** the main thread.

So no need to call `Dispatch.main.async` in the Firebase callbacks. You are already on the main thread.